# Xcode C++ library location

Tags: c++, xcode

I'm pretty new to Xcode and C++. I was wondering if there is a place to store custom libraries so that I don't have to drag them into each project. I'd like to be able to just say '#include "mylib.h"'

Is that possible?

Comment: isn't this what "`/usr/local/lib`" is good for?  :-)

Answer (score 0):

Mac like any other system use /usr/include, /usr/lib and /usr/local/include, /usr/local/lib.

Additionaly in XCode < 4.2 you can find headers and libs in /Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.X.sdk/usr/lib

in XCode >= 4.3 this sdk is inside /Application/Xcode.app bundle
you can assign include directory using -I parameter to specify include dir path, and -L to specify lib dir path. Both can be add in build settings in project settings